# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Unable to find the InitialContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory

Tags: jms, websphere, adobe, tibco, tibco-ems

I have developed TIBCO EMS standalone client developed which is used in Adobe Livecycle to send requests to tibco queue. Getting the below error.

Going by the error, not able to load InitialContextFactory.

## Error snapshot below.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Unable to find the InitialContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory.
org.apache.aries.jndi.ContextHelper.getInitialContext(ContextHelper.java:149)
org.apache.aries.jndi.OSGiInitialContextFactoryBuilder.getInitialContext(OSGiInitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:50)
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:696)
javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:319)
javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:254)
javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:228)
com.citigroup.gsu.edelivery.engine.utils.TibcoEMS.ServiceLocator.getInstance(ServiceLocator.java:34)
com.citigroup.gsu.edelivery.engine.utils.TibcoEMS.TibcoEMSClient.SendTibcoEMSMessage(TibcoEMSClient.java:36)
```

## Code snippet details below.

TibcoEMSClient.java:36

```
serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.getInstance(user,password, providerUrl);
```

ServiceLocator.java:34

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, providerContextFactory);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
ic = new InitialContext(env);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like classpath issue. You need to add tibjms.jar to your project classpath or to the applications server classpath. The Jar file you can get from tibco installation folder for example C:\tibco\ems\6.0\lib or download from tibco web site. If you are using ssl you may also need tibcrypt.jar

How to add tibjms.jar to classpath depends on your application server. 
For WebSphere this document may help https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.0.1_january_2011/html/tib_ems_integration_guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=appint.5.17.htm&single=true

Please see steps:

> Add TIBCO Enterprise Message Service as a JMS Provider This section
>   configures WebSphere to uses TIBCO Enterprise Message Service as a JMS
>   provider.
>
> 1. Start the WebSphere application server.
> 2. Start the WebSphere Administrative Console.
> 3. In the WebSphere navigation pane, choose Resources > JMS > JMS providers.
> 4. In the content pane, click the New button.
> 5. Enter the following values for the required properties:   Name      TIBCO Description   TIBCO Enterprise Message Service Classpath
>      EMS_HOME\lib\tibjms.jar External Initial Context Factory
>      com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory External Provider
>      URL    tibjmsnaming://localhost:7222
> 6. Click the OK button.
> 7. Click the Apply button.

Comment: Should I specify the tibjms.jar in the WebSphere Classpath.

Comment: Yes. You need the jar inside your project classpath or Websphere class path

Comment: You normally don't want to add jars to WebSphere's classpath. If you add a JMS Provider to WebSphere, you can specify a classpath for it specifically. This is what we did in the past.

Comment: @dbreaux I am not an expert in WebSphere. this document may help https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.0.1_january_2011/html/tib_ems_integration_guide/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=appint.5.17.htm&single=true